# require ERC20 transferFrom

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

I have a deposit function where I want to `require` that the `transferFrom` worked and if not it should be reverted with "Transaction declined by user".

```
function deposit(uint256 _amount) external {
        require(_amount > 0, "The amount should be greater than 0");
        require(usdcContract.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _amount, "The USDC balance should be at least the specified amount");
        require(usdcContract.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount), "Transaction declined by user");
        ...
        addressToFunds[msg.sender] += _amount;
```

I wanted to test this, but realise that this does not work. It gives the following error `AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with Transaction declined by user, but other exception was thrown: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string`

```
it("Transaction should fail, if not approved", async () => {
      // setup user USDC balance for interaction with contract
      let balance = await USDCContract.balanceOf(user.address);
      expect(balance).to.equal(0);
      
      let txn = await USDCContract.transfer(user.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("5")); // user1 received 5 USDC
      await txn.wait();
      
      balance = await USDCContract.balanceOf(user.address);
      expect(balance).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("5"));
      
      // approval by user left out 
      // txn = await USDCContract.connect(user).approve(fund.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("5"));
      // await txn.wait();
      
      await expect(fund.connect(user).deposit(ethers.utils.parseEther("5"))).to.be.revertedWith("Transaction declined by user");
 
    })
```

Is this the right way, I'm doing it? Or obsolete?

Comment: [Consider using custom errors instead of revert reason strings](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/). Compared to revert reason strings, custom errors are easier to work with, more gas efficient, and more elegant. [Here's an implementation of ERC-20 which uses custom errors](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-contracts/blob/923f3150625427dc79bbb1a100e50ad0007c33b7/contracts/token/erc20/ERC20.sol).

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg and then I can test it with something like that `await expect(contract.connect(signer).deposit(ethers.utils.parseEther("5")).to.be.revertedWith(
        CustomError,
      );` right?

Comment: that depends upon the JavaScript library that you're using. I recommend using Waffle. Check out my [Hardhat-based template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template).